# what is the percent of smart contract usage?

Tags: go-ethereum

Does anyone has statistics of how much transactions are doing pure Ether transfer, versus the transactions that execute some contract?

The idea is to find out how much smart contract transactions are executed in reality. To answer a question of this nature: Is Ether is used more as a currency or is it mostly used by smart contracts?

Also , what is the current ratio of external accounts (human) vs internal(contract)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can also get this information straight from etherscan! Here's a quick summary (as of the writing of this post):

Total transactions (internal+external):
[77274392](https://etherscan.io/txs)

Internal transactions:
[38180777](https://etherscan.io/txsInternal)

So internal transactions represent about **49 percent** of all transactions (and external transactions represent the rest)!

I can't really make any conclusions about what this data really means. I'm genuinely surprised by how equal the percentages are. I have a feeling that exchanges represent a huge % of these transactions.

Comment: wow, 50% is a lot, I am surprised too. I thought few people were using smart contracts.

Comment: but how could be transactions of the exchanges? they shouldn't use contracts. or do they create a token for every user account at the exchange?

Comment: My guess is that most of the internal transactions right now are ERC20 token transfers

Comment: this answer is wrong...Internal transactions are not transactions that trigger code execution, they are the messages sent when a contract communicates with another contract